# Clarification regarding NestJS Interceptors order of execution

Tags: nestjs

I have a controller handler that return a string.

```
// Controller.ts

import { Controller, Get, UseInterceptors } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UpperInterceptor } from './upper.interceptor';
import { LowerInterceptor } from './lower.interceptor';

@Controller()
export class AppController {

  @Get()
  @UseInterceptors(LowerInterceptor, UpperInterceptor)
  getHello(): string {
    return 'Hello'
  }
}
```

I have attached 2 interceptors, Lower and Upper which do change the string case accordingly to their name.

```
// lower.interceptor.ts
import { CallHandler, ExecutionContext, Injectable, NestInterceptor } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators'

@Injectable()
export class LowerInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {

  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    console.log('lower')
    return next
      .handle()
      .pipe(
        map((e) => {
          console.log('calling lowercase')
          return e.toLowerCase()
        }),
      );
  }
}
```

```
// upper.interceptor.ts
import { CallHandler, ExecutionContext, Injectable, NestInterceptor } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators'

@Injectable()
export class UpperInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {

  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    console.log('upper')
    return next
      .handle()
      .pipe(
        map((e) => {
          console.log('calling uppercase')
          return e.toUpperCase()
        }),
      );
  }
}
```

I would expect the return value to be `HELLO` but it is `hello`

As far as I can see Lower interceptor is executed first, but the map that it pipes to the observable is executed after the map of the Upper interceptor and the return string is hence `hello`.

Do you know why the interceptors are executed in order as expected but the callback they map through pipe is executed in inverted order?

Is this related to nest or just rxjs? Sorry but I am new to both.

Answer (score 2):

It's an RxJS thing. [This Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-p3vie3) essentially shows what's going on, even if not explicitly written in your server. Each interceptor is getting chained into the next one. The interceptors follow a First In, Last Out stack frame, so you see lower being logged before upper, but then you see the output as lowercase instead of uppercase like you originally expected. I've added in some `tap` methods as well to illustrate where in the call chain everything happens with Observbales.

Answer (score 1):

The order is defined by the order of the decorator arguments `@UseInterceptors(...)`. It works like a function call stack in recursive calls. After executing the handler (return from the function), the call stack is unwound again:

```
1. Lower Interceptor
2.   Upper Intereptor
3.     next.handle()
4.   Upper Interceptor (Transform to uppercase)
5. Lower Interceptor (Transform to lowercase)
```